# How to show div top of the page on pageload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two html pages.`page1.html` and `page2.html`.I want to click on href in page1 and i want to ridirect to `page2.html` but specific div at the top of the page.

**Page1**

`<li><a href="page2.html#profileData">Profile View</a></li>`

**Page2**

`<div id="profileData">
</div>`

Only single page contains many div.I want when `page2.html` page open then `ProfileData` div on top of the page.

How can i do this with jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href="page2.html#profileData"`, this function will scroll to the element #profileData

```
$(function(){
  // get hash value profileData
  var scrolldiv = window.location.hash;
  // now scroll to element with that id
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scrolldiv).offset().top });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response,where i place this function??In javascript file?

Comment: so it will need to go in a JavaScript file or <script> tags included on the page the scroll function will happen on e.g page2